# How chainlink VRF be used in dynamic NFT drop rate similar to thetan box in thetan arena game

Tags: nft, chainlink

I am trying to create a application where user can purchase item. The item has a NFT with some drop rate.

How VRF can be utilized in this process to make sure it is secure, verifiable and at  the same time NFT should be based on probability drop rate ex. The drop rate is as per table attached.

[image]

Comment: You can get random number(s) within a range (0-100% of X) using Chainlink VRF like this https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices/#getting-a-random-number-within-a-range and then implement internal logic in your smart contract to mint NFT based on drop rate

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.